# Can someone access my database from outside my server?

Tags: php, database, security

I was trying to "[google hack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_hacking)" my site to see what happened (I recently read about it), I googled for `site:www.x.com intitle:"index of" "server at" + db`.

And found a `.inc` file in the three directory.

```
<?php 
    class clsSettings
    { 
        var $site   = "localhost"; 
        var $sitedb = "x"; 
        var $siteuser = "x"; 
        var $sitepass     = "x";
    } /* settings */
?>
```

Can someone access my database from outside my server?

Should I be worried about this sensitive info exposure?

Note: I removed sensitive info with `X`s.

Comment: Yes. Exposing such information increases the risk on your website. and Yes, you can tell google to stop indexing certain pages/paths using the robots.txt file (http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449), but you should prevent access to this information from the server itself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Storing script files outside web root](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034474/storing-script-files-outside-web-root)

Comment: @Aziz but can someone login to my DB?

Comment: Those files should be stored outside of your document root do they're not publicly accessible

Comment: @Yim: it depends on many factors, but exposing your password will increase the risk significantly.

Answer (score 3):

That's why you don't name your PHP files anything other than `.php`.  You *can* configure the server to parse `.inc` files, or any file extension, as PHP if you wanted, but this isn't a common configuration, especially on shared servers.

If you can see the contents of your files that contain your password, then so can the rest of the world.  Also, Aziz's comment about changing robots.txt does **not** help you at all.  In fact, you can call attention to the things you are hiding this way, as anyone trying to get into your site won't follow the rules within robots.txt.

It is also common to not allow automatic directory indexing, unless you need it for some specific reason.

Comment: well, robots.txt does prevent google from indexing it (assuming google indexers respect robots.txt), but I agree, that is not the solution to the security problem that he has. thanks. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

I trust you fixed this issue by renaming the file extension to .php.

Execute this command with a new password on your server (i.e. though SSH):

```
mysqladmin -u root -p 'oldpassword' password newpass
```

Then change the password of all the referenced PHP files.

Also you may want to create a "Robot trap" to stop bots that do not follow your robots.txt file, see http://www.fleiner.com/bots/#trap for more info. However note that this is a weak protection mesure.

Also you can add this to your .htaccess in the WWW root to stop directory listings:

```
Options -Indexes
```