# Hostinger File Access | Wokring outside public_html folder | php website

Tags: php, web, public-html

I am new to web development.

I recently made a mcq based web app, which just tracks how many wrong attempts it took the user to get the correct answer.

I successfully uploaded it on hostinger.
[www.website.com/company](http://www.website.com/company)
it opens fine

I uploaded the company folder as a subfolder in public_html

No in the company folder I have a config.php file which has the database connection.

I dont want it to be visible. I tried taking it out of the public_html folder and then just putting it directly outside of it but it shows that the file is not being found.

I tried doing with the css file as well to check but the file does not get displayed. It shows error 404.

So I need help in how can I access files outside of the hostinger and how would the path look like first thing.
Second **Is there anyway to hide files in the public_html folder? Like can I just hide the certain file whereas my other functions can access it but the user cannot see it.**

I have tried everyway but go no solid response, I would actually like help to hide it in the public_html folder itself

Comment: You could block the file from being served publicly via nginx/apache/iis (varies by what software you are running). You also should be able to call the script from outside public dir. It is not really clear how you current have tried. Can you add related code?

Comment: I am using hostinger.

Comment: That's a company, need to know what server application you are running there

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Storing script files outside web root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034474/storing-script-files-outside-web-root)